# How do I get PowerPoint drag with MouseWheel to work?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010

here in the office in some computers you can, when zoomed in a slide, go around by dragging the screen with the *mouse wheel pressed*. Like the *hand tool* in Adobe products. This does not work but in all of the computers.

All computers are under Windows 7 Professional, 64 bits, MS Office 2010 Home and Office, all mice are Microsoft, can't remember the exact model, they are like the one in this image, regular optical mouse:

[image]

I installed the MS software Intellipoint, and in some computers works (dragging the slides) and in some others don't. I just wanted to know if there's a known update to make this work or if I have to activate it somewhere?

Comment: There are a number of things which influence how the mouse functions; the OS, the software version, the mouse drivers, and the mouse itself. Not all mice have the exact same features or capabilities. Have you verified all the mice are exactly the same, using the exact same drivers and the exact same OS? Give us some details about the equipment you are working with. Also, tell us what you've done to try to resolve this yourself.

Comment: Thans Charlie, I've edited the question with some other details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after a while I found the answer. It seems that this functionality I was looking for works thanks to an add-in that the computers at my office have, and is the Think-Cell add-in.

Once this is installed you can use the mouse like the "hand" tool in Adobe products by holding the mouse wheel pressed.